# Conditional range in a parametric plot

Tags: plotting, syntax

I have a program that needs to be done like this:

```
ParametricPlot[
  equation,
  If[x < 1, {x, 0, t}, {x, t, 2}]]
```

But *Mathematica* didn't seem to recognize the values of xmin and xmax in the range of the independent variable x, nor the variable x itself.

The simplest solution, in my opinion, would be to insert `If` expressions into the range itself, something like this:

```
ParametricPlot[
  equation,
  {x, If[x < 1, 0, t], If[x >= 1, t, 2]}]
```

**EDIT:**

This is why I needed to do this. I needed to paint the curve when $0<t\leq T$, but "delete" it when $T<t\leq2T$

[image: Spirograph]

Comment: Why don´t you describe what you *want* to do rather than prescribe something that most likely will not work syntactically?

Comment: @YvesKlett The short answer would be why you can't put a variable/function in the plots range position? ParametricPlot[equation,myrangefunction[a,b]]. Being myrangefunction[a_,b_]:={x,a,b} I don't know why that doesn't work.

Comment: it will help to post a self contained small complete example than fragments. This way, one can see better what you are trying to do.

Comment: Didn't recognize or it threw an error? I think it should throw an error because `ParametricPlot` has the `HoldAll` attribute that you can read about in the docs, which means it won't evaluate arguments. However, doing it like in your first example and changing it to `Evaluate@If[...` should work as long as t is defined.

Comment: @Anon in the first example I also tried with Evaluate@If[... and it didn't work.

Comment: The iterator `{x,y,z}` cannot be changed retroactively as a function of `x` itself within `ParametricPlot`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that. No it def. can't. If you want something very fancy, you can always create two separate plots and combine them using `Show`.

Comment: Why don´t you *post* the code for your function? Making that up as well is unattractive.

Comment: If @anon has a possible answer to the question, I'm not opposed to reopening, but the question as asked should be improved for the benefit of future visitors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some preliminary definitions:

```
With[{r1 = 2, r2 = 1, 
      c1 = {Cos[#], Sin[#]} &, c2 = {Cos[4 #], Sin[4 #]} &, c3 = {Cos[2 #], -Sin[2 #]} &},
 f1[t_] = (r1 + 2 r2) c1[t] - 0.85 r2 c2[t];
 f2[t_] = r1 c1[t] + 0.85 r2 c3[t];
 ]
```

A `Dynamic` solution.  The offset `0.0001` is to keep `ParametricPlot` from complaining and not evaluating.  (It does not work if the end points of the domain are the same.) [`Clip`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Clip.html) is a convenient way to keep the end points of the domain at the end points of a period.

```
Column[{
  Manipulator[Dynamic[t0], {0, 4 Pi}],
  Dynamic@
    ParametricPlot[{f1[t], f2[t]},
     {t, Clip[t0 - 2 Pi, {0, 2 Pi - 0.0001}], 
         Clip[t0,        {0.0001, 2 Pi}]},
     PlotStyle -> Lighter@Blue, PlotRange -> 5]
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

An animation. First the frames:

```
movie = Table[
   ParametricPlot[{f1[t], f2[t]},
     {t, Clip[t0 - 2 Pi, {0, 2 Pi - 0.0001}], 
         Clip[t0,        {0.0001, 2 Pi}]},
     PlotStyle -> Lighter@Blue, PlotRange -> 5],
   {t0, 0, 4 Pi, 2 Pi / 50}];
```

Then `ListAnimate[movie]` or `Export["foo.gif", movie]`:

[image: Export["foo", movie]]

Comment: +1, I know it's tangent to the problem in the OP but since I went at it for a while with a set of equations that produced a very similar result as this, but not quite, could you hint as to how you found those equations? Ty.

Comment: @Anon They are an [epicycloid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Epicycloid.html) and a [hypocycloid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hypocycloid.html), with the traced point on the rolling wheel set slightly inside the rim (`0.85 r2`).

Comment: @MichaelE2 Actually it's .8 but that's good enough ;)

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing, but perhaps the OP is looking for something like this.

```
With[{t = .9},
  Module[{range},
    range = If[t < 1., {x, 0., t}, {x, t, 2.}];
    ParametricPlot[{x, .5 x}, Evaluate@range, 
      PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 1}}]]]
```

[image: left-plot.png]

```
With[{t = 1.1},
  Module[{range},
    range = If[t < 1., {x, 0., t}, {x, t, 2.}];
    ParametricPlot[{x, .5 x}, Evaluate@range, 
      PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 1}}]]]
```

[image: right-plot.png]

#### Update

Now that I hae a better understanding of what you want, I suggest you get the effect by controlling the coloring of the curve, rather than by adjusting its range. Here is an example.

```
Manipulate[
  ParametricPlot[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, tt},
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
    PlotStyle -> {Thick},
    ColorFunction -> (If[#3 > 2 π, White, Black] &),
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False],
    {tt, .1, 4 π, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: circle.png]

Comment: Some black points can be seen on the white part. I knew I could make it with colors, and also putting a white function in top of the blue one, but I don't see this as a good resolution, what if some other plots are under this curve?